# how to create pointer to nested objects in C?

Tags: c, pointers, object

I have function where I call function setBoolChannels:

```
int parseLayerFile(WRAPPER_t * w, char*filename){
setBoolChannels(w->layer_files[file_no].command_orders[tmpi]);
}
```

The parseArgs is called from main:
`parseArgs(w, argc, argv)`;

How to access the object w->layer_files[file_no].command_orders[tmpi] in the function parseLayerFile to access its members to update? The function is empty at the moment, but I was not able to access get the object.

```
void setBoolChannels(LAYER_COMMAND_ORDER_t * cmd, char * token, uint32_t n){
cmd; // here I got cmd (LAYER_COMMAND_ORDER_t *) 0x7
}
```

Cannot access memory at address 0x7 ...

I can access whole WRAPPER_t object but I am curious if it is possible to access the nested object (to create a pointer to it).

Here are types which I use:

```
typedef struct LAYER_COMMAND_ORDER_
{
  uint16_t * id;
} LAYER_COMMAND_ORDER_t;

typedef struct LAYER_FILE_
{
  LAYER_COMMAND_ORDER_t * command_orders;
} LAYER_FILE_t;


typedef struct WRAPPER_
{
    LAYER_FILE_t * layer_files;
} WRAPPER_t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given definitions of `parseLayerFile()` and `setBoolChannels()` the compiler should complain about incompatible parameters since `parseLayerFile` tries to pass a struct where `setBoolChannels` expects a pointer. A pointer would be passed like this:

```
int parseLayerFile(WRAPPER_t * w, char*filename){
   setBoolChannels(&w->layer_files[file_no].command_orders[tmpi]);
}
```

Supposedly that still produces the same error message:

> Cannot access memory at address 0x7 ...

Address 0x7 is just a small offset from address 0x0. That likely means you are using a null pointer to some struct or array and try to access a field in the struct/array.

In your case this probably means that `w->layer_files[file_no].command_orders` or `w->layer_files` is `NULL` or otherwise uninitialized.

Comment: That's correct. I have found it too but hadn't time to post an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for example :

```
WRAPPER_t wrapper;
wrapper.layer_files = malloc(...);
*(wrapper.layer_files) = SOME_VALUE;
```

just look at the expression struct.innerPointer as 'reguler' pointer and act on it as if.

Comment: So how to declare the argument in function? I cannot pass the SOME_VALUE to the function until the pointer is declared.

Comment: do you want to allocated an array on layer_files inside the function or outside it?

Comment: I don't want allocate anything. The object is allocated. I need to create pointer to the object which I am passing to function. I need to access the object. The object already exists nested in wrapper object of type WRAPPER_t .

Comment: Not exactly. The pointer should be to `w->layer_files[file_no].command_orders[tmpi]` where file_no and tmpi are indexes ... layer_files is array of structs LAYER_FILE_t and command_orders is array of structs LAYER_COMMAND_ORDER_t ... check the code: `setBoolChannels(w->layer_files[file_no].command_orders[tmpi]);`

Comment: so just put & before all the expression: &(w->layer_files[file_no].command_orders[tmpi])

Comment: No it does not work, this produces same message, it is not possible to access that address.